# how to make sections that are not displayed for non-"screen" media type

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to define a section of HTML that will not be displayed if the 
media type is "print" instead of "screen". 
I've tried:
{code}

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
     @media print
     { .not_print: { hidden: true; }
     }
     @media screen
     { .not_print: { hidden: false; }
     }         
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <span class="not_print">
     <p>This should not be displayed if printed / print previewed.</p>
     </span>
   </body>
  </html>
```

but the section is not hidden if the page is printed / print-previewed by Firefox (36.0,Linux x86_64).

Any ideas ? Anyone managed to define HTML sections that won't be printed?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Oops, looks like markdown did not recognize my code section. Trying again.

Comment: You have to remove colon after class name , here you go
     { .not_print { hidden: true; }
     }

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for something like the following:

Only shown when printed:

```
@media print {
    div {
       display: block;
    }
}
@media screen {
    div {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Or only shown on a screen:

```
@media print {
     div {
       display: none;
     }
}
@media screen {
     div {
       display: block;
     }
}
```

Comment: I should mention I was trying to define a CLASS of section that would not be printed, not ALL "div" elements, so I ended up using:

Answer (score 0):

I should mention I was trying to define a CLASS of section that would not be printed, not ALL "div" elements, so I ended up using:

I should mention I was trying to define a CLASS of section that would not be printed, not ALL "div" elements, so I ended up using:

```
    @media print
     { .no_print { display: none; }
     }
     @media screen
     { .no_print { display: block; }
     }         
    ...
    <div class="no_print">
      this section will not be printed ...
     </div>
```